# Angular Material 2: Selected tab gets deselected on focus lost

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm using Material 2 to do tabs with navigations in angular. The routing part works fine but when I change mouse focus by clicking somewhere on the page, the active tab is no longer selected.

the code in HTML:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="abc">abc</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="def">def</a>
</nav>
```

What could be the cause?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `routerLinkActive` directive to apply class on links based on current URL.

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="abc" routerLinkActive="active-link">abc</a>
  <a mat-tab-link routerLink="def" routerLinkActive="active-link">def</a>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
.active-link{
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: thanks! how come the link only becomes active only after i focus change? for example when i navigate to "def" , the link only becomes green when I focus change after navigation